# How to add a fake, dummy, null printer in CUPS?

Tags: printer, cups

I'm writing a piece of software that supports multiple printers. In order to test it, I need to add multiple printers to my CUPS server. How can I do that?

I want to add a few fake printers that will send the jobs directly to /dev/null. That way, I can watch the "completed jobs" list in CUPS interface and observe if my software is using the correct printer for each job.

Comment: isnt this correct "lpadmin -p lp0 -E -v /dev/null -m raw"

Comment: See also [creating a dummy printer](http://superuser.com/q/455198/130012).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One solution is to install **[cups-pdf](http://www.cups-pdf.de/)**. It adds a virtual printer that writes PDF files. There are several tutorials on the web about how to install and configure it; since I use Gentoo, I've read [Gentoo-wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20130317035335/http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/CUPS_-_PDF_Printer), which also mentions [Sabayon wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918220252/https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Installing_CUPS_Print_to_PDF_driver).

**cups-pdf** virtual printer has a configuration file in `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`, and by default all PDF files are written to `/var/spool/cups-pdf/${USER}/`. On [Debian-based distros](https://sources.debian.org/src/cups-pdf/3.0.1-14/debian/patches/01_debian_changes_to_cups-pdf_conf.patch/), [such as Ubuntu](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pdf/tree/debian/patches/01_debian_changes_to_cups-pdf_conf.patch), the default path was changed to `${HOME}/PDF/`.

There are a few limitations, though:

- Since there is only one configuration file, multiple PDF printers will save to the same directory.
- It is impossible to print "raw" data (using, for instance, `lpr -o raw`). Even sending a PDF file as a raw job will not work. Raw print jobs will generate a blank PDF file with just an empty page.

Even with these limitations, it works perfectly for my needs.

---

Footnote: if the user is using Gnome, or printing through a GTK+ application, then there is already a "Print to File" pseudo-printer at the print dialog. Thus, why should the user still want to add a virtual PDF printer? Here are a few reasons:

- That "Print to File" is specific to GTK+, and is not available for non-GTK+ applications. (maybe KDE has a similar feature, but I'm not sure)
- It makes possible to generate a PDF from Flash "applications" that were designed for printing. For instance, the [PocketMod](http://www.pocketmod.com/v2/).
- Adding a virtual printer to CUPS makes it possible to test printing using shell scripts or other software that talks directly with CUPS. This is specially useful for developers while testing their applications.
- It is possible to "share" this virtual printer with the local network. Not exactly useful, but possible.
- It is possible to attach a post-processing command to be executed right after the PDF file has been saved.

Comment: What is the device URI for CUPS-PDF ? I can't figure out how to add it as a printer using `lpadmin -p pdf -v cups-pdf:/`

Comment: @DrBeco That command-line works for me. It creates a new virtual printer using cups-pdf. Note, however, the printer was initially rejecting all jobs, so you might need some more configuration. Or just add `-E`: `lpadmin -p virtpdf -E -v cups-pdf:/` (as shown in the other answer)

Answer (score 11):

**The Cups Forum has a more complete/accurate answer to this question.**

The answer is that the device URI should be set to file:/dev/null

So in my Ubuntu setup:

- Device URI: file:/dev/null
- Make and Model: Local Raw Printer

Which works for me perfectly.

I searched the Cups forum again and found this:

[Commandline Null Printer Setup in Cups Forum](http://www.cups.org/pipermail/cups/2010-January/020165.html)

**In your cupsd.conf:**

```
FileDevice yes
```

**Setup Printer**

```
lpadmin -p nowhere -E -v file:/dev/null
```

**Testing Printer**

```
who |lp -d nowhere
```

Comment: I am just looking at my printout now: fine details, vibrant colours it plain jumps off the page at me. ... hey waitaminute ....

Comment: Thank you.  I needed a dummy printer in my Virtual Machine to screenshot some instructions. :)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for `wine` too.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a printer that outputs to `/dev/null` with `lpadmin`:

```
$ sudo lpadmin -p myprinter -E -v file:///dev/null
```

This will be written to `/etc/cups/printers.conf`, but you can also view printers with `lpstat`:

```
$ sudo lpstat -s
myprinter accepting requests since Thu 22 Jan 2015 11:04:46 AM GMT
system default destination: myprinter
device for myprinter: ///dev/null
```

Note that [you may need to enable FileDevice in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf on old Linux distros](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhelv5-list/2007-March/msg00228.html).

To make your new printer the default, use `lpoptions`:

```
$ sudo lpoptions -d myprinter
```

Comment: How to remove it?

Comment: @Richard Use `lpadmin -x myprinter` or the web interface.

Answer (score 5):

One of the best solution is to use `ippserver`. It comes with `CUPSv2.2.2` and higher. You can alternatively get the project from here: [IPP sample implementations](https://github.com/istopwg/ippsample/).

According to the description on the [manual page](http://istopwg.github.io/ippsample/ippserver.html):

> ippserver is a simple Internet Printing Protocol (IPP) server conforming to the IPP Everywhere and IPP Shared Infrastructure Extensions (INFRA) specifications. It can be used as a standalone print server and/or a very basic infrastructure server between standard IPP clients and IPP proxies conforming to the INFRA specification.

To use it, all you need to do is run `ippserver "My cool printer"`, and it will create a virtual printer with the name `My cool printer` for you. It runs like a web server and listens on specific ports.

In case you need multiple printers, you can run the server on multiple ports using `ippserver "My other cool printer" -p 8888`.

You can even supply printer attributes using an attributes file. For instance, your printer supports by default high quality prints, you can add the following attribute in the attributes file:

```
ATTR enum print-quality-default high
```

and run the server using:

```
ippserver "My high quality cool printer" -a attributes-file.txt
```

**References:**

1. [PWG IPP Sample](http://istopwg.github.io/ippsample/index.html)
2. [CUPS ipptoolfile man page](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-ipptoolfile.html?TOPIC=Man+Pages)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://inai.de/linux/adm_virtualprinter:

> ### Virtual printer in CUPS
>
> To create a printer in CUPS that sends the data nowhere (like
>   `/dev/null`), there are many ways. This page uses the `socket://`
>   method.
>
> ### Set up xinetd first
>
> What we need is the TCP Discard service on port 9. Xinetd has it
>   built-in, so we can just use that. Make sure that the following
>   definition is available in xinetd's configuration file(s), usually
>   `/etc/xinetd.d/discard`. It should contain a service like the
>   following:
>
> ```
>     service discard
>         type            = INTERNAL
>         id              = discard-stream
>         socket_type     = stream
>         protocol        = tcp
>         user            = root
>         wait            = no
>         disable         = no
>         FLAGS           = IPv6 IPv4
> ```
>
> Run `rcxinetd reload` to reread the configuration files and activate the new `discard` service.
>   Or use `rcxinetd start` if xinetd was not already active.
>
> ### CUPS printer
>
> Now go to the CUPS web frontend and add a new printer. As destination,
>   use `socket://localhost:9/`, as printer choose something that looks
>   featureful, for example the "HP 2500C Foomatic/pcl3". That's all there
>   is to it.