# CUPS : Creating a dummy printer directing to dev/null

Tags: linux, printer, printing, cups

I used following command , is there anything wrong with it ?

```
lpadmin -p lp0 -E -v /dev/null -m raw
```

Comment: Why, does something not work?

Comment: parameter wise is it correct? actually i have only the access to the remote-server and I cant access the client program actually submitting jobs to it.

Comment: why the vote down?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
lpadmin -p lp0 -E -v file:///dev/null
```

So it's `file://`  with `/dev/null`   (like the `http://` syntax).